# How will I get remaining string from a long_string - Substring_of_log_string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

**I have a long String: s1= "I am asking a question related to python String" and I have a substring: s2 = "related to python String" I am looking for the result "I am asking a question" which is (s1-s2) any efficient way to do it?**

Comment: Python does not regard that as subtraction but replacement: `result = s1.replace(s2,"")` ... though you will be left with a trailing space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace()`.

`sliced_string = long_string.replace(short_string, '')`

Keep in mind it will remove all the occurences of the short_string.

Use `replace(short_string, '', 1)` to remove only one occurence.